# Recorder Application

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an android application which is simple a voice recorder application, and now I want to add one more functionality into it.
Can anyone please help me to make a recorder which records the audio clips of 2 minutes.

```
 public void intervalRecorder(long addOfThree){

        //This  code is not working properly

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mIntervalRecorder.setEnabled(false);
                mStopRecordBtn.setEnabled(false);
                mRecordBtn.setEnabled(false);


                k=1;
                testPath=UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_audio_record.3gp";
                pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/Recorder Application/" +testPath;

                setupMediaRecorder12();
                try {
                    mediaRecorder12.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder12.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(RecordActivity.this,"Recording...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        },addOfThree);
        mediaRecorder12.stop();
        uploadAudio();
        Toast.makeText(RecordActivity.this,"Stop...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        k=0;

        mIntervalRecorder.setEnabled(true);
        mStopRecordBtn.setEnabled(true);
        mRecordBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }

`

private void setupMediaRecorder12() {
        mediaRecorder12 = new MediaRecorder();

        mediaRecorder12.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

        mediaRecorder12.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

        mediaRecorder12.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);

        mediaRecorder12.setOutputFile(pathSave);
    }
```

I don't know why I am getting `NullPointerException`.

**Logcat error**

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.stop()' on a null object reference
            at com.shashank.recorderapplication.RecordActivity.intervalRecorder(RecordActivity.java:299)
            at com.shashank.recorderapplication.RecordActivity$5.onClick(RecordActivity.java:242)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
            at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12752)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26211)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Hello shashank, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please describe what is not working well? Is there any error message on Logcat?

Comment: what is the problem? your question is not clear? what do you mean by "This code is not working properly"? also dont use android-studio tag when your question is not related to android-studio itself and just use it.

Comment: where you define `mediaRecorder12`? Did you initialize it?

Comment: @DiegoMalone  whenever I call the function `intervalRecorder `, it gives a NullPointerException.

Comment: is it solved ??

Comment: @JohnJoe Not yet , is there any other way to record the audio clips of exactly 2 minutes ???

Comment: solve your null pointer exception first.

Comment: @JohnJoe thank you so much, now it is working.

Comment: @shashankkarn how you solved?

Comment: @JohnJoe Start functionality of media recorder must be outside of the handler and Stop will be inside of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

//Start functionality must be outside of the handler and Stop will be inside of the handler

```
public void intervalRecorder(long addOfThree){

    g=1;
    k=1;
    testPath=UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "Custom_audio_record.3gp";
    pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Recorder Application/" +testPath;

    setupMediaRecorder();
    try {
        mIntervalRecorder.setEnabled(false);
        mStopRecordBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mRecordBtn.setEnabled(false);

        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(RecordActivity.this,"Recording...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            try{
                PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(RecordActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    uploadAudio12();
                    Toast.makeText(RecordActivity.this,"Stop...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    k=0;
                    g=0;
                    mIntervalRecorder.setEnabled(true);
                    mStopRecordBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    mRecordBtn.setEnabled(true);

        }
    },addOfThree);
}
```